# Summarize the Table in Sql

Tags: sql

I want to join four tables and get total sales(Value*Quantity) for each month.
each transaction have to get monthly wise(July2018)
Example: 
Agent_ID  Agent Name Total sales(monthly wise)

```
Agent table
----------
Agent_ID
Agent Name
Agent address



Transaction table
-----------------
Transaction_ID
Transaction_Date(12/7/2018)
Agent_ID
Transation_Status


Transaction Detal table
-----------------------
Transaction_ID
Item_code
Quantity


Item Table
----------
Item_code
Item_name
Value
```

Pls support for this scenario

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: What DBMS do you refer to?

Comment: What's the format of `Transaction_Date`? Is it a date or a varchar?

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. Take a look at [mcve] before you start.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that the `Transaction_Date` is `DATETIME` OR `TIMESTAMP` field, Here is a `Mysql` query that could give you the desired result.

```
SELECT SUM(Value * Quantity) as total, DATE_FORMAT(Transaction_Date, '%Y-%M') date
FROM Agent JOIN Transaction USING (Agent_ID)
JOIN Transaction_Detail USING (Transaction_ID)
JOIN Item USING (Item_code)
GROUP BY Agent_ID, date;
```

Comment: Personally, I think it's a bad idea to suggest some solution without the OP trying anything.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your query. Your are trying to sort by month-year.

```
select concat(DATENAME(month, cast(Transaction_Date as varchar)), year(cast(Transaction_Date as varchar))), sum(t4.Value * t3.Quantity),  from table t1
inner join transaction_table t2 on t2.Agent_ID = t1.Agent_ID
inner join transaction_detail_table t3 on t3.Transactdion_ID = t2.Transaction_ID
inner join item_table t4 on t4.Item_code = t3.Item_code
group by concat(DATENAME(month, cast(Transaction_Date as varchar)), year(cast(Transaction_Date as varchar)))
```

Comment: Personally, I think it's a bad idea to suggest some solution without the OP trying anything.